# Codeigniter displaying message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I dont know whats wrong with my code..

I am trying to display message from database, but i keep on getting error that $results are not defined.

Controller

```
public function getMessages()
    {
        $this->load->model('get_message');

        $data['results']= $this->get_message->getMessage();

        $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
    }
```

Model

```
 <?php
class get_message extends CI_Model{
    function getMessage(){
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM messages");
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
    <div id="Main">
        <?php
        foreach($results->result() as $row){
            echo $row ->id;
            echo $row ->user_username;
            echo $row ->text;
            echo $row ->posted_at;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: here is what my code looks like now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller

```
 public function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('get_message');

            $data['results']= $this->get_message->getMessage();

            $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
        }
```

Model

```
<?php
class get_message extends CI_Model{
    function getMessage(){
       $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM messages');
       return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <div id="Main">
        <?php
        foreach($results as $row){
            echo $row['id'];
            echo $row['user_username'];
            echo $row['text'];
            echo $row['posted_at'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This code works. if it doesn't you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: if this doesn't work then print_r(data['result']);
tell what it outputs.

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: data

Comment: tried, changing everything as you said.. still the same erro

Comment: my bad..use this print_r($data['result']); after all other change i proposed

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: result
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I deleted something from the view which is not necessary for this solution

Comment: Hi, your code looks correct.. but its still gives me the same error.. i dont even know what to do

Comment: i am 100% confident the error lies some where else. did you autoload database library? i ran your code in my machine. it is working fine. if you use like $row->id then use $query->result().

Comment: Ok.. the code works.. there is only one problem.. it only works when i URL myself.. but not when i log in and it gets me to the page...

Comment: Nice to know but didn't understand your problem, basically which i told you these code was not issue after we post some fix.

Comment: so how would i go about making this code work after a user logs in? because i see the page after log in.. but this code doesnt work. what should i do?

Comment: ur login controller and related code need to be posted may well as another question

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong element to the view.

```
$data['result']= $this->get_message->getMessage();
             ^
```

Should be

```
$data['results']= $this->get_message->getMessage();
             ^
```

Also in Model,

```
return $query->result();
```

Should be:

```
return $query;
```

And in view,

```
foreach($results as $row){
```

Should be

```
if ($results->num_rows()) { // IN CASE, THE RESULT HAS NO ROWS.
  foreach($results->result() as $row) {
```

Comment: I have edited it.. your code has completely broken it :/
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in C:\wamp\www\application\views\home_view.php on line 11

Comment: My code doesn't have errors. Please debug the code.

Comment: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\application\views\home_view.php on line 11

and still says Undefined variable: results

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: results

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you send data as `result`

```
 $data['result']= $this->get_message->getMessage();
```

Access in view like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){

}
```

You used as `results` in foreach instead of `result`

Comment: Try `print_r($data['results']);exit;` to check data is there or not in controller.

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: data

Comment: try this in model `return $query->result_array();`

Comment: Check this in model.to check data.
`$res =  $query->result_array();
print_r($res);exit;`

Comment: that didnt cahnge anything :/ i know it should work, as it worked before i done the login form...

Answer (score 0):

View :

Your code

```
foreach(**$results** as $row){
}
?>
```

change to

```
foreach(**$result** as $row){
}
?>
```

Comment: 13 records in the message table

Comment: please provide all content for "views/home_view.php"

Comment: Model

 <?php
class get_message extends CI_Model{
    function getMessage(){
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM messages");
       var_dump($query->result());
exit;
//return $query->result();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to get result in some other variable in your controller function -

```
public function getMessages()
{

    $this->load->model('get_message');

    $data['msgesult']= $this->get_message->getMessage();

    $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
}
```

And then in view -

```
<div id="Main">
    <?php
    foreach($msgesult as $row){
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['user_username'];
        echo $row['text'];
        echo $row['posted_at'];
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi, i realized the code does work.. but only wehn i URL myself and call getMessages... but if i try to just get there normally it doesnt show :/